# What's the key to the field "this certificate is encoded for the following purpose(s)" in ssl certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, oid

In the property page of an SSL certificate (accessible in windows using mmc/certificates), each certificate is associated with a set of intended purposes looking either like this :

> Protects e-mail messages
>
> Proves your identity to a remote computer
>
> Ensures the identity of a remote computer
>
> Ensures software came from software publisher
>
> Protects software from alteration after publication
>
> All issuance policies

Or like this :

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.3.4

How can I get the correspondance between those strings and a human-readable format ?

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers are Object Identifier strings (aka OID)

There are several public repositories for OIDs ([example](http://www.oid-info.com))

For this string :

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.6449.1.2.1.3.4

the first part of the OID [refers to Comodo](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.6449&submit=Display&action=display), but the last part of the identifier is not available. It seems the only solution in this case is to ask Comodo directly.